# Does each managed thread have its own corresponding native thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to know if creating a managed thread in .Net (by calling `Thread.Start()`) causes that exactly one native thread to be created in background? 
So is there a corresponding native thread for a managed threads?
If yes, when a managed thread waits or sleeps, does it mean that the corresponding native thread also waits or sleeps?

Comment: Why do you think it's a different thread?

Comment: @BlackFrog: It's a legitimate question. Why would anyone bother distinguishing between "managed thread" and "native thread" if the two were always *guaranteed* to be the same thing in the first place? The OP didn't come up with that distinction; [Microsoft did](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx "MSDN article 'Managed and Unmanaged Threading in Windows'").

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, a .NET Thread maps to a native operating system thread on all current CLR hosts.

There's an option to map it to something else in the hosting api through the [ICLRTaskManager interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164438.aspx), like a fiber, but that is not actually implemented in any of the main-stream hosts.  The SQL Server team at the .NET 2.0 time frame attempted this but the project was abandoned when they could not make it reliable enough.  This was not tried again.  Technically you could run into a custom hosted CLR, started by an unmanaged program, that implemented this mapping but the odds are rather low.

Comment: Thank you for providing a clear-cut answer to this question. I've stumbled upon the following document https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/threading.md which seems to be discussing this issue and I would be grateful if you could update the answer in a way that also breaks-down the phrase <<Managed threads are not necessarily mapped to a single native thread (and may not be mapped to a native thread at all). >> Is there a contradiction or am I misinterpreting the aforementioned phrase? Thank you again!