# Does code in a .NET Task ultimately run on a CPU or CPU Core via native Windows Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

Referring to the following post, which leads one to believe a .NET Task executes without native OS threads being involved. Is this true?

[Difference between Task (System.Threading.Task) and Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493421/difference-between-task-system-threading-task-and-thread)

EDIT

In reviewing duplicate questions I couldn't find an answer directly addressing the question that instantiating a .NET Task class will ultimately execute on a native OS thread. They refer to threads but either not discerning between managed and native OS threads or just to managed threads. The only thing that could be duplicate is my own answer to one of those questions.

But in digging myself, it would seem there is no "magic" with .NET that avoids native OS threads. There are no changes to the Windows kernel to allow this. Such is consistent with my own OS experience a couple of decades ago. In short, there is no app code anyone can write that does not run on a native Windows OS thread.

[About Processes and Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/about-processes-and-threads)
[Managed Threading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/)

Also:

[Windows Kernel Internals Process Architecture](https://slideplayer.com/slide/7488011/)

[Architecture of the Windows Kernel](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~zwang/files/cop4610/Fall2016/windows.pdf)

[Evolution of the Windows Kernel Architecture](https://indico.cern.ch/event/62731/attachments/1005779/1430710/slides.pdf)

Comment: All code runs on native OS threads.  Tasks don't use _a dedicated_ native thread.

Comment: SLaks is correct.

Comment: See [Does each managed thread have its own corresponding native thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476595/does-each-managed-thread-have-its-own-corresponding-native-thread)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:  it depends.

Tasks which involve some computational work, would run on a thread and normally that would be a thread from the thread pool.

Long-running tasks, i.e. created with option `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` run on a dedicated thread, which is created for them.

I/O Tasks, like `await stream.ReadAsync()` *do not* have a thread at all.  The operation is sent to the IO device, and the CPU is free to do whatever it pleases. Only when the device is ready with the requested data, it *interrupts* the CPU, it does some low-level processing and ultimately the OS gets a thread from the thread-pool to complete the task and make the result available to your program.  More details [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).