# What's the link between System.Threading.Thread and System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread

Tags: c#, multithreading

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668809) explains what to in order to give a name to a thread.

The problem, however, is that this speaks about `ProcessThread`, and I would like to know how to link such a `ProcessThread` with the firstly created `System.Threading.Thread`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does each managed thread have its own corresponding native thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476595/does-each-managed-thread-have-its-own-corresponding-native-thread)

Comment: `ProcessThread` is a native thread, which in current implementations is mapped 1:1 with a managed thread.

Comment: @Charlieface: and how can I use that mapping? When I loop through a `foreach` loop (`foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)`), how can I access the original `System.Threading.Thread` objects?

Comment: Why do you have only a List of ProcessThread(s)? It sounds to me that only the Threads started by you via the Thread class are of relevance to you. So why don't you just remember those in whatever structure useful to you and forget about ProcessThread(s).

Comment: @Ralf: in my application, threads get created and started all over the place. It goes even that far, that threads get created and started up multiple times. I would like to avoid this, simply by asking "Tell me which threads are currently running, I will search for the thread I want to start up here, but when the thread is already running, I won't do that.".

Comment: Then i don't know what you want to give a name to and what it should tell you. In such system threads often come from a threadpool or are spawned/reused because of async/await code. Those threads will constantly do completely different things that they have been reused for. You might name one 'A'and the other 'B' but it might do what initially 'A' has been tasked to do with and vice versa. I see only a chance to use a meaningful name for a thread you started explicitly via the thread class. For them you actually know what they will do and have an idea of their lifetime.

Comment: @Ralf: Currently, threads can be started from different reasons,  so I have threads, getting starte 20-30times a day.

Comment: @Ralf: in my application, threads are used for performing specific tasks (they are not running through the entire codebase, they just perform their own tasks). The problem is the management of those threads: several objects can start up threads, and sometimes there even are threads which might create threads of their own, the idea is to have a "defence" system, which can restart threads if they have crashed but it's a complete mess. Therefore I was thinking of a check to see if a thread is already running or not, and only in that case is it allowed to a new thread to be created.

Comment: Cleaning up that mess still sounds to me that you should start implementing some sort of management of those threads and maintain independently what is running or run. So have your own "List" of Threads and ignore ProcessThreads and get actual control of the mess instead of throwing some more complexity at it that will be hard to understand and likely will just increase the mess . You may try digging into this [package](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd) that seems to do it by directly interacting with the Net Runtime. I tried understanding it but lost track.

Comment: ...I'm wondering why you even want to deal with low-level `Thread` primitives considering the hazards involved, whereas TPL is a far more usable alternative...

Comment: @Dai: what is TPL? Also: I'm working with an application, based on a self-made library, based on `System.Threading.Thread`, so I dont have a choice.

Comment: "TPL" is shorthand for `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>` - e.g. `Task.Run()` (instead of `new Thread()`, and letting .NET's thread-pool handle scheduling for you instead of _trying to be too smart_ - it also includes things like `Parallel.For/ForEach` which automatically dispatch work to the best number of concurrent threads based on your computer's hardware (i.e. there's no point spinning up 100 threads when a machine only has a 12-core CPU).

Comment: @Dominique knowing which is the first thread won't help *at all* with your real problem. Threads aren't obsolete. Creating a new thread is expensive so threads should be reused whenever possible. .NET itself uses threadpools. The entire ASP.NET stack, HttpClient, and a lot of built-in .NET classes depend on them. That includes most the async operations, especially the network-related ones

Comment: @Dominique it's hard to help without looking at the actual code. Simply using `async/await` eliminates the need for most extra threads. Networking libraries, including web servers/services, use a *pipeline* of processing tasks instead of having one member handle everything, allowing them to use a set number of thread on each pipeline step. .NET provides the Dataflow classes for this. You can also use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to process the results of asynchronous operations using a controlled number of reusable threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my application, threads get created and started all over the place. It goes even that far, that threads get created and started up multiple times. I would like to avoid this, simply by asking "Tell me which threads are currently running, I will search for the thread I want to start up here, but when the thread is already running, I won't do that.".

As suggested by @Ralf, the path of least resistance will be to take full control yourself. Instead of asking "which threads are currently running", you could hydrate a data structure with the new thread(s) whenever you create it. Allowing you to query it later. In essence your problem is one of dependency management.

It's worth pointing out that your application brings it legacy. As mentioned in the comments, working directly with low level threads brings it own slew of problems. To bring the application into the current decade, you could refactor your app to use `Task` instead of `Thread`.

The same state management applies. You can keep track of your tasks using a data structure (or dictionary) and then monitor their progress through [task.TaskStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-7.0).